# Number Division Theory

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have a JavaScript function that takes in a user number (total amount placed on a betting table in denominations of 50) and returns an Array of the optimum chips (lowest # required) to form each stack.

My function works, the correct array for each value tested is output - but since this should be running on the client browser with a fast response time for smooth UI I feel like the code is not optimised.

Is there a better, more efficient (+ mathematically solid) way of computing the same output?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
//number will be validated before running through function to make sure it has a factor of 50.

function chipStack(number) { 
    var k = 0; //1k chip
    var f = 0; //500 chip
    var t = 0; //300 chip
    var o = 0; //100 chip
    var fi = 0; // 50 chip

    k = Math.floor(number / 1000);
    var number2 = number % 1000

    if (number2 === 0) {
        return [k, f, t, o, fi];
    } else {
        f = Math.floor(number2 / 500)
        var number3 = number2 % 500
    }

    if (number3 === 0) {
        return [k, f, t, o, fi];
    } else {
        t = Math.floor(number3 / 300)
        var number4 = number3 % 300
    }

    if (number4 === 0) {
        return [k, f, t, o, fi];
    } else {
        o = Math.floor(number4 / 100)
        var number5 = number4 % 100
    }

    if (number5 === 0) {
        return [k, f, t, o, fi];
    } else {
        fi = Math.floor(number5 / 50)
        var number6 = number5 % 50
    }

    if (number6 === 0) {
        return [k, f, t, o, fi];
    } else {
        return "Something isn't right " + number6;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you could write the code to *look* more compact, but inlined as it is here should execute fast.

Comment: There won't be performance problems, but there are several poor programming practices in that code (`else` after `return`, `var` inside conditional code, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compress the code as follows. It doesn't check for early exit conditions, but since it's running on the front-end anyway, i.e. not at high volumes, the performance won't be noticeably degraded.

```
function chipStack(n){
    var chipValues = [1000,500,300,100,50];
    var stack = [];
    chipValues.forEach(function(e,i){
        stack.push(Math.floor(n / e));
        n -= (stack[stack.length-1] * e);
    })
    return stack;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for mathematical background…

In general, the [Change-making problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) is a knapsack problem, which is NP-hard.  However, [for sane sets of currency denominations, a simple greedy algorithm works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13557979/1157100).

For your set of denominations, { 1000, 500, 300, 100, 50 }, the greedy algorithm applies.  (There is, however, an amount with two optimal solutions: 600 = 500 + 100 = 300 + 300.)  Therefore, your greedy algorithm and @MartVandeVen's simplified implementation of it will work.